# How to select HTML elements whose type has a dash in them

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

`$('foo\\-bar')` works.

I want to do `$('foo\\-bar', '<foo-bar>foobar</foo-bar>')`, but this will not work. Why? And how can I select all `foo-bar` tags in my string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape the dash. Just use

```
$("foo-bar")
```

or

```
document.querySelector("foo-bar")
```

`$('foo\\-bar', '<foo-bar>foobar</foo-bar>')` doesn't work, because the context (second parameter) is also a root element in your context, which is why `foo-bar` cannot be found as a child of the context element/string.

This would work on the other hand:

```
$("foo-bar", "<div><foo-bar></foo-bar></div>")
```

Comment: Thanks :) But why $("work-title", "<work><work-title>tada</work-title></work>") will not work?

Comment: I don't know. It does for me on Firefox 40.

Comment: My code was collising with jQuery... Problem solved!